# Can Eri's quirk bring back the dead?

Tags: my-hero-academia

This was asked by someone in another website but seems to have limited answers, or at least not enough to satisfy myself, so I am asking here.

Since Eri can, correct me if I'm wrong, rewind a person's body, can Eri also rewind a dead body back into a living one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there has been no event yet in the manga where Eri was shown to have reverted a dead person back to life.

What we know is that:

- Her quirk can only affect a person's physical state, as mentioned by Aizawa in **Chapter 161**
- Her quirk can erase a person's existence completely, as mentioned in **Chapter 156**, when her father accidentally touched her

Personally, this is still vague. For example, does a person have a soul? Because if he/she does, will the soul alongside the body be also affected? What is only known is that her quirk can only affect the physical state of those she is in contact with or within her vicinity. There is a possibility that, if a person does have a soul, it can also be affected, *unless the manga dismisses it entirely*. Is there a guarantee that if a person has a soul, would his/her soul still be near its physical body upon death? Near enough to be affected by her quirk?

However, assuming that a person does not have a soul and death is just another physical state of the body in the *My Hero Academia* world, then theoretically, she could.

There are still much to know about her quirk that we can only speculate what could be or could not be possible. As far as I know, that manga has yet to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

Since human memories are stored physically, it depends on if Eri's quirk would also rewind that person to also have those stored memories which would collectively make a person, or if the body would be rewinded to before death but the mind would be gone.

I'm not sure because I don't think there has been any evidence on which one is correct though

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but I'd assume that if Eri did happen to resurrect someone, they would probably be a body with no soul unless her quirk can resurrect the mind.

I have a small theory that's probably not accurate, but the heroes & villains in *My Hero Academia* are able to power up as I've seen with Toga. So, if Eri powers up, it (might) allow her to bring peoples' souls alive with the original part of her quirk, which is turning back time on a person's physical state.